# All IBOutlets are nil

Tags: ios, swift, null, iboutlet

Hello I am initializing viewController using this code:

```
 var aboutUsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AboutUsViewController") as AboutUsViewController
```

After this I move to `aboutViewController`. However all my `IBOutlets` on `aboutViewController` are `nil`! Why is that so?
I am using MMDrawer library in order to have side bar menu.

```
 var aboutUsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AboutUsViewController") as AboutUsViewController


        var aboutUsNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: aboutUsViewController)

        var appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

        appDelegate.centerContainer!.centerViewController = aboutUsNavController
        appDelegate.centerContainer!.toggleDrawerSide(MMDrawerSide.Left, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

On the side bar I am choosing about us menu item and after I am creating AboutViewController and moving it to the left... The problem is that when I initialize my controller , outlets are nil

I AM also having such kind of problem when using pageViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {


let pageTitles = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"]
var images = ["long3","long4","long1","long2"]
var count = 0


var pageViewController : UIPageViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reset()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func reset() {
    /* Getting the page View controller */
    pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageViewController") as UIPageViewController
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self

    let pageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    self.pageViewController.setViewControllers([pageContentViewController!], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    /* We are substracting 30 because we have a start again button whose height is 30*/
    self.pageViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 30)
    self.addChildViewController(pageViewController)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController.view)
    self.pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}



func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).pageIndex!
    index++
    if (index >= self.images.count){
        return nil
    }

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = (viewController as PageContentViewController).pageIndex!

    if index<=0 {
        return nil
    }
    index--
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func viewControllerAtIndex(index : Int) -> UIViewController? {
    if((self.pageTitles.count == 0) || (index >= self.pageTitles.count)) {
        return nil
    }
    let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as PageContentViewController

    pageContentViewController.imageName = self.images[index]
    pageContentViewController.titleText = self.pageTitles[index]
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index
    return pageContentViewController
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pageTitles.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
    }

}



class PageContentViewController: UIPageViewController {


@IBOutlet var imageViewMain: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet var labelMain: UILabel!

var pageIndex: Int!
var titleText: String!
var imageName: String!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.imageViewMain.image = UIImage(named:imageName)
    self.labelMain.text = self.titleText
    self.labelMain.alpha = 0.1
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations:{ ()-> Void in
        self.labelMain.alpha = 1.0
    })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation



  // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

I am having problem that label and image outlet is nil!!! The same problem I had using MMDrawer library. The same situation. I am not using segues ! I think because of that outlets are nil

Comment: You've expanded this to show how you're using `aboutUsViewController` (thanks), but you don't show us where you're using this outlet on that view controller which is still `nil`. Which outlet is `nil`? Where does this problem occur?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. The problem occurs on aboutUSViewController. On main board I added labels and control dragged them into aboutUSViewController. I am setting the value of labels in viewdidload. But I am having this weird error that all label outlets are nil

Comment: I found the answer. Instead of creating UIViewController , I created UIPageViewController

Answer (score 17):

I assume you're looking at the outlets immediately after instantiating the scene (you'll also see this behavior if using segues and trying to use the outlets in `prepareForSegue`). But the outlets are not hooked up until after you present/push to that scene, the view is loaded, and `viewDidLoad` is called.

Bottom line, do not try to use the outlets prior to `viewDidLoad` being called (i.e. do not use outlets immediately after instantiating the scene). Instead, pass the needed data to the destination scene (e.g. a `String` property), and the `viewDidLoad` of the destination should then populate the outlet.

For example, you might have a property in `AboutUsViewController`:

```
var message: String!
```

When you instantiate `AboutUsViewController`, you'd set that property:

```
let aboutUsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("AboutUsViewController") as AboutUsViewController // use `as!` in Swift 1.2

aboutUsViewController.message = "some message"

presentViewController(aboutUsViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And then the `viewDidLoad` of `AboutUsViewController` would use that property to populate the outlet accordingly:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label1.text = message
}
```

But you would never have the originating view controller try to set/adjust the outlets of the destination scene. That's the responsibility of `AboutUsViewController`.

---

Just to confirm, are your outlets hooked up properly? The below shows two ways to confirm that they are hooked up properly.

When you select the view controller in Interface Builder and then look in the connections inspector, do you see your outlets hooked up there? In the following snapshot, `label1` is hooked up, but `label2` is not:

[image]

Or when you look at your code, and look at the outlets, do you see solid dots in the left margin (meaning the outlet is hooked up) or empty dots (meaning the outlet is not hooked up)?

[image]

Comment: Hello Rob, I am using MMDrawer library in order to have sidebar! So I am not using perform segue at all. I am just creating viewcontroller and moving it to the left side ... See above, I edited my question

Comment: Understood. (I only mentioned segues because they suffer from the identical problem, and was trying to help future readers who stumbled across this question.) My point is that one of two problems is possible: Either you're using the outlets before the view is loaded (remember, this does _not_ happen when you instantiate the view controller, but rather happens later when the view is actually presented) or else the outlets have not been hooked up properly in IB.

Comment: Rob I am having the same problem when using pageViewController.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function before presenting, which is available on iOS9 and later:

```
    aboutUsViewController.loadViewIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. Instead of creating UIViewController , I created UIPageViewController!!!